# Dynamically Store key inside application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, cryptography, polymorphism, embedded-resource

The scenario is like this i have two applications.
Application A is an encrypting application which encrypts files.
Application B is a decrypting application which will decrypt the file encrypted by A.

The key is generated randomly.
Now the problem is as the key is generated randomly, I don't want to store the key in a text file.
I want to store the key embedded in app b, which would require either having a class value of b being modified by app a or modifying a resource neither of which I am able to find a way to do.

Can anybody help me with this about how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Mandatory reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: @SLaks It cannot be asymmetric encryption. It has to be symmetric. The creation of a CA is also not possible. Did you intend for me to read some particular part of the blog?

Comment: IIRC, C# has a secure key store in it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967325/best-way-to-store-encryption-keys-in-net-c-sharp for some hints.

Comment: @rossum Thanks for the info but isn't the secure key store machine dependent? The application B is to be run on a second machine thats why the key need to be stored also the key will be changed everytime a new file is to be encrypted so the key has to be dynamically set for everyfile thats encrypted

Comment: @Shaumux: Use Diffie-Hellman, or similar to generate a key each time you need one.  That will allow each machine to store the same key in their own secure store.

Comment: @rossum Diffie-Hellman in itself only protects against eavesdropping attacks, not man-in-the-middle attacks. Many client/server models need to be protected against both... Besides, DH is obviously asymmetric in nature.

Comment: Yes D-H is asymmetric in nature. The problem at hand is that application B once generated may not have any contact with application A so a asymmetric algorthm is difficult. Moreover where and who runs the Application B is not known when it is being generated.